# Loading Script Error in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I get this error, but i can not figure out the fix for it:

> Refused to load the script 'http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Is there any way i can remove this error? Here is my json code.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "COD Television Live Checker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The Official Crome Extension of CodTelevision.com - Live Checker",
    "browser_action": 
    {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "main.html"
    }
    "permissions": ["http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/*"]
}
```

and my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<center><span id="status1">No Data</span></center>

</body> 
</html>
```

and finally my javascript:

```
var query = 'http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/...';
jQuery.getJSON(query, function(data) {
    if (data == 'live') {
        document.getElementById("status1").innerText = "LIVE";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("status1").innerText = "OFFLINE";
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use JSONP, but regular JSON. Whitelist the web service URL in `permissions` at the manifest file.

Comment: wait, so how would i do that?

Comment: @RobW like this permissions: ['http://api.ustream.tv']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the correct permission in the manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/*"
]
```

As can be found here in [the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions).

**UPDATE**

I see that you are using the [v2 manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html). In that case you should add the following to your manifest:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://api.ustream.tv; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: look at my updated json code. Is that how it is suposed to be? If so, i get an error

Comment: oh, and where the "*" is, do i need to keep it there or add the rest of the big link with my api key and stuff?

Comment: Depends. It's a wildcard. So with the `*` is thould just work.

Comment: well, with or without it i still get the error about content security

Comment: yes, i am positive, just in case, let me delete it then re-add the package

Comment: yep, i still get the error...do you have a skype so i can share my screen?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflct v2

Comment: If you do not mind, could you edit my code with your code inside it? I do not know where to place it! Thanks!

Comment: Just replace the permission with that.

Comment: i get invalid value for "content_security_policy"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16212/discussion-between-elite-gamer-and-peehaa)

Comment: Indeed, [`http` resources can **never** be whitelisted in the CSP.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing)